# z-index у псевдоэлементов не работает

Tags: css, z-index

Не понимаю почему не работает z-index у ::before. Позиционирование указано. 
Помогите разобраться.

Нумерация списка должна скрываться частично за содержимым списка.

```css
ol {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none; /* Убираем исходные маркеры */
    counter-reset: num; /* Задаём имя счетчика */
}

li {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 5px;
  z-index:100;
}
   li::before {
    content: counter(num) ' '; /* Выводим число */
    counter-increment: num; /* Увеличиваем значение счётчика */
    color: black;
    font-style: bold;
     font-size: 25px;
     position: absolute;
     top:-15px;
     z-index:10:
   }
```

```html
<ol>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убрал z-index

```css
ol {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none; /* Убираем исходные маркеры */
    counter-reset: num; /* Задаём имя счетчика */
}

li {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
   li::before {
    content: counter(num) ' '; /* Выводим число */
    counter-increment: num; /* Увеличиваем значение счётчика */
    color: black;
    font-style: bold;
     font-size: 25px;
     position: absolute;
     top:-15px;
     z-index:-1;
   }
```

```html
<ol>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Если указана тень с прозрачностью и без фона, то не работает.
box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);

Comment: Прошу прощения. Всё работает)